# How to Inject Log4Net Logging through Castle.Windsor in NServiceBus

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, log4net, nservicebus

I would like `NServiceBus` to use the logger provided by the `Castle.Windsor` container, rather than providing it myself directly. Is there a way to achieve this? Following doesn't work as an exception raised on start.

```
public class EndPointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, IWantCustomInitialization, IWantCustomLogging
{
    private ILogger _logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    public ILogger Logger
    {
        get { return _logger; }
        set { _logger = value; }
    }


    public void Init()
    {
        SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(null, Logger);
        Configure.With()
            .CastleWindsorBuilder(Host.Init.CreateSubsystems())
            .RunTimeoutManager()
            .UseNHibernateTimeoutPersister();
    }
}
```

`Host.Init.CreateSubsystems()` returns a `Castle.Windsor` container, with a registered logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply a container alreday bootstrapped w/ a ILogger registered to CastleWindsorBuilder there's nothing else to be done: NServiceBus will use your logger settings as per log4net configuration(separate file or within app.config according to logger registration in the container)

SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(null, Logger); is no needed.

```
public class MessageEndpoint : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        var installerFactory = new MyInstallerFactory();
        container.Install(FromAssembly.This(installerFactory));

        var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
        logger.Debug("Container bootstrapped");

        Configure.With()
                 .DisableTimeoutManager()
                 .CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
                 .JsonSerializer();

        logger.Debug("Bus configured");
    }
}
```